# Index signature with separate types for getters and setters

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Currently, it is possible to make setter support `undefined`/`null` and have `non-undefined`/`non-null` getter:

```js
export interface IProperty<T> {
    get value(): T;
    set value(value: T | undefined);
}

// the following is ok with "strictNullChecks": true
const a: IProperty<string> = {value: ''};
a.value = undefined;
const b = a.value;
console.log(b);
```

I want to make a generic type that allows setting undefined for all properties of an object, see comment:

```js
// this type works, but it also makes getter nullable :(
export type EditableObject<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: EditableObject<T[K]> | undefined;
};
```

This looks bad, but we need such type to start using `strictNullChecks` in a large app.

```js
export function editableScope<T>(item: T, block: (item: EditableObject<T>) => void): void {
    block(item);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `strictNullChecks` at all? Bypassing it with this trick might actually be worse in the long run if you end up using the getter and assuming it isn't `undefined`, e.g here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUoHsAO0wCeAPACoB8yA3gLABQyDyA5hGMgG5wA2ArhABQBKAFzISAbjqNkAZ1Yduffp14RRJZAB9kPEABMIMUBD2DJtAL506AehvIwACxQwsXLlgDuoJsmAzkLABrZG8nZAAiGTAoYAQwADkedwBhZwQgmQjRGL46BCwQaOQ4UQxsPChCImjYkCYKAF4qFT5RAHJ2i3M4ADpWlGbdAyMQE3MCorYAI2RmvoGJwpk3CF6PJn5p3rAsAGUYnyEzIA

Comment: Also, you can just use your current index signature but assert that the getter is non-nullable with the `!` operator: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator

Comment: @101arrowz, 1. I don't want to rewrite everything immediately  2. places, where I'd like to use it, are limited, so other parts of the system can have some benefits of `strictNullChecks`. Due to a large number of properties assertions are too noisy.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible to have index signatures with anything but properties, so you can't really use your existing trick on an index signature. Your best bet is to use non-null assertions with your existing interface, or remove `| undefined` and typecast whenever you set to `undefined` (I recommend non-null assertions).

Comment: I don't see any [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) here; you've got a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), which is different.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot currently get the behavior you're looking for (at the time of this writing, shortly after the release of TypeScript 4.4)

Your `IProperty<T>` type definition is using the support for [separate write types on properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-3.html#separate-write-types-on-properties), also known as "variant accessors", as implemented by [microsoft/TypeScript#42425](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/42425) and introduced in TypeScript 4.3.  But this only works on specific properties whose names are explicitly written out, like `value` in `IProperty<T>`. Variant accessors [do not currently apply](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/42425#issuecomment-826936790) to [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) or [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).

There is an existing feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#43826](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43826) which asks for support for such variant accessors for index signatures and mapped types.  It's currently marked as "awaiting feedback", which means the TS team wants to hear about compelling use cases for such a feature.  So anyone who cares about this might want to go there and describe their use case and give it a ... although it's not clear whether feedback of this sort will really affect when or if the feature gets implemented.

(I see that the OP of this question has [already done this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43826#issuecomment-908550617) in the relevant GitHub issue, so this advice is unlikely to help the OP further, unfortunately.  On the plus side, the OP should hopefully recognize this as being an authoritative and properly sourced answer. ‍♂️)